# How do I convert a float to an Int in Julia v1.0.3

Tags: julia

I am trying to convert float:

```
xmax = maximum(x_holder)-30
convert(Int32, xmax)
```

However, I get the following error:

> ERROR: LoadError: InexactError: Int32(Int32, 30525.8)
>   Stacktrace:

...when I try to convert it. What am I doing wrong? I already looked at the docs and they did not help me.

[docs link](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/conversion-and-promotion/index.html#Conversion-1)

Comment: `30525.8` is not an integer-valued float, and so cannot be converted into an integer. I'm not sure what you were expecting here. As the the answer suggests you'll need to convert it to a floating point number with no decimal part first, typically done using `floor`, `round` or `ceil`, depending on the context of what you are are trying to do. Note, use `?floor` to see how these functions work. You want the method signature `floor(Int, x)`

Comment: `Int32(10.0)` works fine but `Int32(10.05)` will not work. You need to Julia how to deal with the `0.05`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by DNF in the comments, there is no need to go through Int64 on the way to Int32

How about using `trunc`

```
x = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197
print(trunc(Int32, x)) // print 3
print(typeof(trunc(Int32, x))) //prints Int32
```

---

Updated according to concrete example in question

Using `floor`

```
x = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197
xmax = maximum(x)-30
xmaxconverted = floor(Int32, xmax) // -26
print(typeof(xmaxconverted)) // prints Int32
```

Or using `trunc`

```
x = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197
xmax = maximum(x)-30
xmaxconverted = trunc(Int32, xmax) // -27
print(typeof(xmaxconverted)) // prints Int32
```

Comment: julia> y = 30525.8                                                                                                      julia> floor(y)
30525.0

julia> typeof(y)
Float64

Comment: This does not convert it

Comment: Even if I made new vars they would be floats.

Comment: You need to assign the return of `convert(...)', see updated example

Comment: This is a very strange answer. Why round it first to `Int64` and then afterwards to `Int32`, instead of directly to `Int32`?

Comment: @DNF I absolutely agree. I got caught up in the OPs use of `convert` and wanted to provide a solution using that, but that's obviously not the way to go. Updated the answer

Comment: That's good, but I think it would be better if you updated the top part of the answer too, since that appears to provide the general solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as this:

```
round(Int32, xmax)
```

You can supply all sorts of different integer types `T` (as in `round(T, xmax)`), as long as they make sense, and the conversion works. If you want different rounding behaviour, use `floor` or `ceil` instead.

This is preferable to `Int32(round(xmax))`, which takes a de-tour by first making a rounded float and then converting it to `Int32`. And certainly much better than `convert(Int32, round(Int, xmax))`, which is a very strange solution.

**Edit:** In case it's not clear, btw, you need to assign the output of the `round` function to a new variable. The input will not be rounded *in-place*:

```
julia> xmax = 30525.8
30525.8

julia> xnew = round(Int32, xmax)
30526

julia> typeof(xnew)
Int32

julia> typeof(xmax)  # <- still the same
Float64
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this format and it works for Int64 ... , 32, 16 but not for Int8.  I know my results will be small and I want to keep memory to minimum.  What is missing?  Why won't it convert to Int8?  Thx.J

Comment: What number are you trying to round?

Comment: It's a bit complicated, this is my code `round(Int8, floor(rand(TruncatedNormal(150,20,50,250))))`.  For some reason other integer lengths work? Thx. J

Comment: I'm far from my computer, so cannot check, but perhaps the number you are trying to round is too big for `Int8`. Could you try `trunc(Int8, x)` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe:

```
toInt(x) = Int(floor(x))

xmax = toInt(maximum(x_holder)-30)
```